# Is there a way to do a text search on clip names in the video sequence editor?

Tags: import, video-sequence-editor, video

I have somewhere around three dozen different clips and sometimes I need to check what I used. Is there a way to do a text search instead of me scrolling through and checking each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Outliner panel has "Video sequencer" mode and you can search there.

[image]

Also you can search any type of data blocks in Outliner's "Blender File" mode and use filtering to show only some type of data blocks.

Comment: This will save me a ton of time. Thank you very much!